# Why is C#'s Regex.Matches() returning all matches in a single Match object?

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I am having problems in getting all `<script>` and its respective closing `</script>` tags from a html text using via regular expressions, in C#.

I created a sample html that looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>

<script src="adasdsadsda.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script type='javascript'>
        var a = 1 + 2;

        alert('a');
    </script>
</body>

<script></script>
</html>
```

The regular expression I am using is:

```
<script.*>[^>]*<\/script>
```

I often use [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/) to validate/test my regular expressions (highly recommend it!). It shows the regular expression in question captures 3 occurrences (just as I expect).

But C#'s `regex.Matches` is not capturing 3 instances, instead, a single one with all occurrences in it. Is this the expected behavior for the `Matches` method ? I have been using it quite a lot and have been getting all occurrences as a separate capture.

Why is this happening in my case ?

**P.S: In answering the question, if you want to point out that regex is not suited for parsing HTML, please explain how come [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/) and .NET's Regex give different results ? Do they have different regex implementations ?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @SIslam: thanks, but this then means that C#'s Regex implementation is not the same as, say, [regexr](http://www.regexr.com) ? Weird

Comment: Ah! I mean do not parse HTML with <<REGEX>>

Comment: Please see my update in bold ;)

Comment: Yes, they're different flavors. RegExr uses your browser's RegExp engine for matching. Use a .net tester instead (http://regexhero.net/tester/ or http://regexstorm.net/tester). However, .net **[also returns the same 3 matches](http://ideone.com/39gZvN)**. That said, if you have a `>` sign in your JavaScript code, it would fail... Don't use regex to parse HTML, [You can use the HTML Agility Pack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/847051/5290909)

Comment: @Mariano:thanks. I actually moved from Agility Pack to regex because I had the impression it was not working. Will try it again. Thanks for the other directions, will try them as well. Please re-write you comment as an answer so I can give you some points for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/) uses your browser's RegExp engine for matching. It implements a different regex flavor.

[.net](/questions/tagged/.net) uses a unique regex flavor, so I'd suggest using a [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) online tester instead. For example:

- [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/)
- [Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester)

However, the pattern `<script.*>[^>]*<\/script>` should return the same matched text in almost all flavors.

**Code**

```
string pattern = @"<script.*>[^>]*<\/script>";
var re = new Regex( pattern);
var text = @"
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>
        </title>

        <script src=""adasdsadsda.js""></script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <script type='javascript'>
                var a = 1 + 2;

                alert('a');
            </script>
        </body>

        <script></script>
        </html>
    ";


MatchCollection matches = re.Matches(text);
for (int mnum = 0; mnum < matches.Count; mnum++)
{   //loop matches
    Match match = matches[mnum];
    Console.WriteLine("Match #{0} - Value: {1}", mnum + 1, match.Value);
}
```

**Output**

```
Match #1 - Value: <script src="adasdsadsda.js"></script>
Match #2 - Value: <script type='javascript'>
                        var a = 1 + 2;

                        alert('a');
                    </script>
Match #3 - Value: <script></script>
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/39gZvN)</kbd>

---

That said, if you have a `>` sign in your JavaScript code (as part of an IF condition or in a string), it would fail.

There are many reasons not to parse HTML with regex, so please take the following advice: don't use regex. <strike>Instead, you can use the HTML Agility Pack<sup>**[(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/847051/5290909)**</sup>.</strike> **edit:** Instead, I recommend using a [HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1065031/5290909).

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the "if you have a `>` sign in your JavaScript code (which means one should not rely in such a regex, yes).

Comment: I'm trying your advice and am moved to agiliy pack testing again :-)

Comment: As HTML Agility Pack is neither maintained nor HTML5 compatible I would highly suggest using a better solution. There a plenty (for some see the answer of @Veverke).

Answer (score 1):

I am marking Mariano's answer as the solution, but am leaving here the outcome of further research, which is not mentioned in the selected answer:

Seems the most popular options would be, in order of popularity, the following nuget packages:

- Html Agility Pack
- CsQuery
- AngleSharp

I ended up using AngleSharp, which has the advantage over CsQuery of still being maintained/developed.

Comment: Thanks for contributing with your chosen package. I never used the latter and I'll take a look at it.